# Change order of elements in a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

How can I change the order of names in my list so that first name goes before the last name? Here is the sample list I have:

```
names = ['Snow, John', 'Stark, Ariya', 'Baratheon, Myrcella']
```

Comment: As @tommy.carstensen mentioned already - SO expects you to show your effort in solving the task. As a small tip for starters - try to convert each list element to a list and change the order in this new list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
>>> [', '.join(reversed(name.split(', '))) for name in names]  
['John, Snow', 'Ariya, Stark', 'Myrcella, Baratheon']
```

Comment: Does it differ from @tobias_k's answer?

Comment: yes i think comma is missed from @tobias_k's answer.

Comment: @Jainik Well, usually you only separate first and last name with a comma if the last name comes first, so I omitted the comma, since OP did not say otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

`split` the name by `", "`, swap first and last name, and `join` by `" "`. You can do all of this in a (nested) list comprehension:

```
>>> [" ".join([first, last]) for last, first in (name.split(", ") for name in names)]
['John Snow', 'Ariya Stark', 'Myrcella Baratheon']
```

Or shorter, using `reversed` to reverse first and last name:

```
>>> [" ".join(reversed(name.split(", "))) for name in names]
['John Snow', 'Ariya Stark', 'Myrcella Baratheon']
```